# Podio filter_by_view returns too much information

Tags: php, podio

I have not been able to receive anything but a full response when i use filter_by_view

```
$items = PodioItem::filter($appCreds->app_id,$view_id, 
                       array('limit' => $maxItems, 
                             'offset' => $offset, 
                             'filters' => $filters ), 
                       array('fields' => 'items.view(micro)'));
```

The following is the request

```
2018-11-20 17:11:16 200 POST /item/app/20144287/filter/40137598/
2018-11-20 17:11:16 Request body: {"limit":50,"offset":0,"filters":[]}
```

It appears as if the 'fields' array is not being added to the request. Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please use `PodioItem::filter_by_view` but not `PodioItem::filter`